# Grillet, Proposition VI.9.2 (minor detail)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, filtrations, formal-completions

Having a quick problem with a line in Grillet's *Abstract Algebra*, Prop. VI.9.2 on p. 267-8 on the topic of *Filtrations and Completions*. He says that the ideal

$$\widehat{\mathfrak{a}}_j = \{ (x_1 + \mathfrak{a}_1 , \dots , x_i + \mathfrak{a}_i , \dots ) \in \widehat{R}_{\mathcal{A}} \ | \ x_j \in \mathfrak{a}_j \}$$

is the kernel of the morphism $\widehat{R}_{\mathcal{A}} \rightarrow R/ \mathfrak{a}_j$ defined by $(x_1 + \mathfrak{a}_1 , \dots , x_i + \mathfrak{a}_i , \dots ) \mapsto x_j + \mathfrak{a}_j$.

Calling that morphism $\theta$, I have of course no problem seeing that $\widehat{\mathfrak{a}}_j \subseteq \ker \theta$, but I cannot quite see how $\ker \theta \subseteq \widehat{\mathfrak{a}}_j$. It is of course clear that $x_j - x_{j-1} \in \mathfrak{a}_{j-1}$, but I don't see how you go from knowing that $x_j \in \mathfrak{a}_j$ into concluding that $x_{j-1} \in \mathfrak{a}_j$ with that piece of information.

Anyone care to help me?

Comment: Why do you want $x_{j-1}\in\mathfrak a_j$?

Comment: Well, from the definition of $\widehat{\mathfrak{a}}_j$, I need all the $x_i$ to lie in $\mathfrak{a}_j$, or at the very least, that $x_i + \mathfrak{a}_i = y_i + \mathfrak{a}_i$ such that $y_i \in \mathfrak{a}_j$. Thus, at least finding a way to show that $x_{j-1}$ must lie in $\mathfrak{a}_j$ seemed like a good first step forward.

Comment: No, wait! I just misread! Something as simple as a misunderstanding! Embarrassing! Thanks for helping getting my mind there!